# How to do Web Method for List<String[]> in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have the Web Method.

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string[]> getObjective()
{
    List<string[]> objectiveStringList = new List<string[]>();
    con.dbConnect();
    objectiveStringList = con.getObjective();
    con.dbClose();

    return objectiveStringList;
}
```

And also, the query.

```
    public List<string[]> getObjective()
{
    string strCMD = "SELECT objective FROM CorrespondingBall WHERE objective IS NOT NULL";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCMD, conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    List<string[]> objectiveStringList = new List<string[]>();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        objectiveStringList.Add((string[])dr["objective"]);
    }
    return objectiveStringList;
}
```

However, error "HTTP 500 Internal Server Error" message was shown. I have tried it with List Byte Array and there was no error. Does anyone know how can I solved it?

FYI: I am doing an application for Windows Phone 7.

Comment: what is datatype of "objective" ?

Comment: Hi @sangramparmar, it is NVARCHAR(MAX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is not correct.

```
(string[])dr["objective"]
```

you will be getting exception on this line in your webmethod. because  you cannot cast `dr["objective"]` directly to `string[]`.

**Edit:**

As you have mentioned in comments below that datatype is NVARCHAR so you can do this

```
objectiveStringList.Add((string)dr["objective"]);
```

Comment: what is the datatype of objective when you save it?

Comment: then you can simple do this objectiveStringList.Add((string)dr["objective"])

Comment: then why are you trying to convert it to array of string?

Comment: I do not want to display it all at the same time in my application. I have to display it one by one to indicate each level of game.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35894/discussion-between-no-one-and-liu-jia-hui)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public List<string> getObjective()
    {
        string strCMD = "SELECT objective FROM CorrespondingBall WHERE objective IS NOT NULL";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCMD, conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<string> objectiveStringList = new List<string>();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            objectiveStringList.Add(dr["objective"].ToString());
        }
        return objectiveStringList;
    }
```

Comment: what if the OP wants to return List<string[]> and not List<string>

Comment: Hi @sangramparmar, thank you. It worked! However, I would like to know am I still able to call the value out like array in my application?

Comment: @LiuJiaHui You can treat List as Array

Comment: @LiuJiaHui it worked but is objective really a string? ToString() is a very generic method and it is very possible that you have converted some other thing to string.

Comment: @sangramparmar, the datatype is NVARCHAR(MAX).